Change of variable of a n-th derivative
I have to find $\frac{\text{d} ^l}{\text{d} x^l} f(x)$. However, looking closely, $f(x)$ can be expressed as $f(x^2)$, and it is dramatically easier for me to calculate $\frac{\text{d} ^n}{\text{d} y ^n} f(y)$, with $y = x^2$, and $n \in \mathbb N$. What I would need is the generalisation of the change of variables $\frac{\text{d} }{\text{d} x} = \frac{\text{d} x^2}{\text{d} x} \frac{\text{d} }{\text{d} x^2}  = 2x \frac{\text{d} }{\text{d} x^2}$ for the n-th step, either in my specific case ($y=x^2$) or in general.
I see this question that seems to ask the same thing, and a comment on the question gives an answer that seems in the right direction but it is difficult to me to adapt or generalise. This other question exists but the answer just directs to Faa di Bruno's formula which I understand has to be used to get the answer I want but is not exactly the direct answer.
Can anybody help?

Is this helpful in any way?

@HackR Not really, it was quoted in the second answer and it is just some application of the Faa di Bruno's formula. I'd need some more direct help.

That article I linked essentially is an exposition on Faa Di Bruno's formula (Theorem 2 specifically). it tells you how to compute all the components explicitly via the preceding formulae.

@HackR If you have a more constructive and explicit answer please write it, insisting on the linked article, that I did see but whose notation is definitely not my bread and butter, is not helping me at all

After researching more, the clearest paper that answers it is this one. I can't find where I saw it linked first, but there is also this other question that I missed yesterday, whose first answer is almost correct, as the $i!$ in the denominator is also to the power of $m_i$. I post here the correct answer in the most readable way to me:
$$
\frac{\partial ^n f\big(g(x)\big)}{ \partial x ^n} = \sum_{(m_1,...,m_n)} \frac{n!}{m_1! \cdot ... \cdot m_n!} \frac{\partial ^m f\big(g(x)\big)}{ \partial g ^m} \prod _{i=1} ^n  \left( \frac{1}{i!} \frac{\partial ^i g(x)}{ \partial x ^i} \right) ^{m_i}
$$
where $(m_1, ..., m_n)$ are the tuples satisfying the Diophantine equation
$$
\sum _{i=1} ^n  i\ m_i = m_1+2m_2+... n\cdot m_n = n
$$
and $m = \sum_i m_i$. Plugging in $g(x) = \eta = x^2$, knowing that $\frac{\partial ^i g(x)}{ \partial x ^i} = 0$ for $i\geq 3$, we get
$$
\sum_{(m_1, m_2)} \frac{n!}{m_1! m_2!} (2x)^{m_1} \frac{\partial ^{(m_1+m_2)} }{ \partial (x^2) ^{(m_1+m_2)}} f (x^2 )
$$
